# How to make a gauge chart dynamic?

Tags: python, plotly, data-science, data-analysis, streamlit

I have made the following code for a static Gauge chart.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
fig = go.Figure(go.Indicator(
        mode = "gauge+number+delta",
        value=180,
        domain = {'x': [0, 1], 'y': [0, 1]},
        title = {'text': "Speed"}))
        # delta={'reference':380}
        fig
```

Please help me in making a dynamic Gauge chart where `value` changes.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic? Do you mean the user can change it?

Comment: I meant the data is of real time